# HTML5 video on iPad live from iPad camera

Tags: ipad, html, safari

is there a way to display video live from iPad's camera in HTML5 web app? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Eventually you will be able to do this using the getUserMedia / Stream API but this is [not currently supported on iOS Safari](http://caniuse.com/stream).